# How I use the Google Map API with referrer restriction on webservice

Tags: web-services, google-maps-api-3, referrer

I have a Google Map API key with HTTP Referrer restriction, in JavaScript embed method its working fine, but I need to use the same key for web services in PHP.

By using the file_get_contents() method I am not able to use the service, it simply returns:

```
{    "error_message" : "Browser API keys cannot have referer restrictions when used with this API.",    "routes" : [],    "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED" }
```

Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed that web service is called from the backend server. No guarantee that referrer will come in request, however, the IP address of the server will come. The restriction that you can use with web services is by IP address, not by referrer. You cannot use the same API key for client side Map JavaScript API and server side web service requests. Just generate another API key, set IP restriction for your server and that it.